# Getting full HTML as a mail from google app scripts rather than the evaluated output

Tags: html, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to send an email to the person who fills my form. But I am getting the whole HTML code as the output rather than the evaluated version of it.

Any help??

***code.gs***

```
function doPost(e) {
   
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var last=sheet.getLastRow();
  var dataRange = sheet.getRange(last, 1, 1, 4);
  var data = dataRange.getValues();
  for (var i in data) {
    var row = data[i];
    var emailAddress = row[2]; 
//    var email_address = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();
    var htmlTemplate=HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('email');
    htmlTemplate.name=row[1];
    var htmlBody= htmlTemplate.evaluate().getContent();
    var subject = 'Sending emails from a Spreadsheet';
    GmailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject,  htmlBody);
    }
  }
```

***email.html***

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <body>
    <p>from html <?= name ?></p>
  </body>
</html>
```

***current output***

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <body>
    <p>from html Bob</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace the following code with modification that shall work in your case, since you are trying to send an email, you should use `createHtmlOutputFromFile`, and to replace the content with dynamic value, `replace` function is easier to write, you may refer to my version on `html template` also

**From:**

```
var htmlTemplate=HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('email');
    htmlTemplate.name=row[1];
    var htmlBody= htmlTemplate.evaluate().getContent();
    var subject = 'Sending emails from a Spreadsheet';
    GmailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject,  htmlBody);
    }
```

**To:**

```
 var htmlTemplate=HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('email').getContent();
    htmlTemplate = htmlTemplate.replace('#NAME', row[1])
    var subject = 'Sending emails from a Spreadsheet';
    GmailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject,'',{ htmlBody:htmlTemplate});
    }
```

**Email template** (body part), so that `#Name` will be replaced by sheet value:

```
<body>  
    <p>from html #NAME</p>
  </body>
```